# Cereal: Shared serialization function across enums

Tags: c++, serialization, enums, rtti, cereal

Lets suppose I have something like:

```
enum t_color { BLUE=0,RED,GREEN};
vector<string> TAG_color={"BLUE", "RED", "GREEN"};

enum t_colores { AZUL=0,ROJO,VERDE};
vector<string> TAG_colores={"AZUL", "ROJO", "VERDE"};
```

I want to use (in cereal) a common save_minimal, such as:

```
  template <class Archive,typename T > inline
  std::string save_minimal( Archive const &, typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<T>::value, T >::type const & t )
  {
    std::string ret="Unknown";
    if ( std::is_same<T,t_color>::value)
    {
      ret=TAG_color[t];
    }
    else if (  std::is_same<T,t_colores>::value)
    {
      ret=TAG_colores[t];
    }
    return ret;
 }
```

It compiles but seems like cereal is ignoring the template. It just use the "integer" value of the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep... it is doable (but not directly through cereal):

```
#define SERIALIZE_ENUM(enumname)                                               \
template <class Archive> inline                                                \
std::string save_minimal( Archive const &, t_##enumname const & t )            \
{                                                                              \
  return std::string(TAG_##enumname[t]);                                       \
}                                                                              \
template <class Archive> inline                                                \
void load_minimal(Archive const&, t_##enumname & t,std::string  const& value ) \
{                                                                              \
  int a=0;                                                                     \
  for (auto const &tag:TAG_##enumname)                                         \
  {                                                                            \
    if ( tag == value )                                                        \
    {                                                                          \
      t = static_cast<t_##enumname>(a);                                        \
      return;                                                                  \
    }                                                                          \
    a++;                                                                       \
  }                                                                            \

namespace cereal { 
  SERIALIZE_ENUM(color)
  SERIALIZE_ENUM(colores)
}
```